# Using a Draw function in JS to create many objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using Javascript and html to making an interactive isotope grid, From 1H to 72Fe, which is 513 total isotopes. Each element has a different number of isotopes. So far I've just been copying and pasting the draw command for every single one, like below. Is there a way I can write a function that can do this?

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  // hydrogen
  ctx.fillRect(1, 1, 20, 20);
  ctx.fillRect(1, 21, 20, 20);
  ctx.strokeRect(1, 41, 20, 20);
  ctx.strokeRect(1, 61, 20, 20);
  ctx.strokeRect(1, 81, 20, 20);
  ctx.strokeRect(1, 101, 20, 20);
  ctx.strokeRect(1, 121, 20, 20);
```

I've tried writing this, but it doesnt seem to work

```
var x = 181;
var y = 121;
var i;
function draw() {
for (i = 0; i < 19; ++i) {
 ctx.strokeRect(x, y, 20, 20);
 y += 20;

 }
}
```

Comment: Use for loop and conditionalize the isotopes based on your requirement if that helps

Comment: Note that you'll also need to figure out how "position in your list of isotopes" makes to "x/y coordinate" - as long as you can come up with a rule for that, you can use a `for` loop to draw all the boxes you need, where you need them.